# Multimeter can't measure current. Maybe broken?

Tags: current-measurement, multimeter

So basically when I put red jack to 10A mode it shows amperage fine, but when I switch to other, it shows 00.0 eveywhere, even when I set to micro amperage it doesn't react to my tongue and skin. It shows Voltage and Resistance fine. The only problem is that it doean't react with smaller currents. Maybe the reason is that I've tried to measure 0.5A in 200mA mode?

Edit: Never mind, the fuse is actually destroyed.

Comment: You probably blew the fuse in the low-current circuit.

Comment: @PeterBennett nope, the fuse seems to be fine, nothing exploded. Well anyways, I will try replacing one later.

Comment: What kind of multimeter is it? Does it have a separate jack for low current range?

Answer (score 5):

Yes you probably blew the fuse. The low current fuse is typically 200mA, although 500mA is also common. Depends on the *counts* of the multimeter.

If the resistance is working fine, you can try testing the fuse with it. Fuses usually break right at the center, away from the end caps which dissipate heat. The center is thus the hottest. But low current fuses, or if the fuse wire had a kink in it... could break off center (usually at the solder joint behind the end cap due to soldering stress).

added: to test if multimeter is working:

1. Verify that voltage source is correct
2. Calculate and add a resistor in series (make sure that resistor can handle the power dissipation)
3. Short out multimeter fuse terminals
4. Connect multimeter and check current
5. Remove short from fuse terminals

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgMThc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Yup the fuse is blown.

Comment: My freshly replaced fuse has around 20 ohm resistance, but I still don't get current measured.

Comment: Fuse can't have 20 ohm resistance. even 20 milli ohm would be too much. Your new fuse might be bad too. Why not TEMPORARILY short it out with a wire and CAREFULLY see if it works (only do this if you know what you are doing, and have a big resistor in SERIES with your multimeter).